# FLOW3 requires the PHP setting "magic_quotes_gpc" set to Off. (Error #1224003190)

Tags: aop, php, magic-quotes-gpc, typo3-flow

While configuring FLOW3 on mac, I modified the `php.ini` in terms of setting `magic_quotes_gpc = off` and on restarting server I get the `magic_quotes_gpc = off` by browsing `http://localhost:8888/MAMP/phpinfo.php`
But on running:

> $ ./flow3 kickstart:package Acme.Demo

I get the following error message:

> FLOW3 requires the PHP setting "magic_quotes_gpc" set to Off. (Error #1224003190)

Can anyone have an idea whats going wrong with it?

Comment: Are you sure you modified the right `php.ini`. Like I can see, you are using MAMP. The path should be something like: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php?.?.?/conf/php.ini`.

Comment: i just opened the php.ini at Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini mannually and added 
; Magic quotes
magic_quotes_gpc = off
About "Are you sure you modified the right php.ini". Yes, as i have only 1 php.ini when i searched it through mac

Comment: Did you manage to get around this? I have the same exact problem and can't turn off magic quotes.. yet. Despite being set to off by default in the .ini file

Comment: Later I configure flow3 on windows and it get well configured there

Comment: Try run `php --ini` in terminal to find out where your php.ini is.

Answer (score 4):

You call phpinfo() through a browser, right? But kickstart uses the PHP
CLI binary. I bet you have another binary and/or another configuration for
that one.

Try php -i and **look at the path for the config file(s)** and the values of
the relevant settings.

Make sure any config file you edit is actually used by the PHP binary you call!

Comment: ya you are right its magic_quotes_gpc => On => On
but i have only one 1 php.ini residing at Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini. Where should i set magic_quotes_gpc = Off now?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using MAMP Pro, editing the php.ini file directly results in it being overwritten when MAMP Pro restarts. I had to edit through the MAMP Pro GUI to turn off 'magic_quotes_gpc'.

In MAMP Pro, go to

```
File > Edit Template > PHP > [The PHP you're using, in my case PHP 5.3.14 php.ini]
```

(img link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToUqF.png).

There, you can look for 'magic_quotes_gpc = On' and set that to 'magic_quotes_gpc = Off'. Save the file and restart MAMP Pro.

If you only see 'magic_quotes_sybase = Off', which happened to me, I modified it with these lines:

```
; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off    

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

(img link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsyPw.png)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Eventually you could also do the easy way and disable it in a `.htaccess` file.

This code should work:

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
```

Comment: tried it earlier for executing the code in browser and it works there but while running it through CLI, the error is still there